# API Goverment rules in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-design

I would like to implement automatic rules of API Goverment in a WSO2 API Manager platform like, for example, validating context with a regular expresion, or version numbering or API name or API resources endpoint naming or parameters, etc.

I checked in version 2.6.0 (and previous versions of major 2) that it can be done in jaggery apps of publisher, but this is a mix of data and presentation (view structure with js and html) and it is not a clear and right way to implement it.

Is there any rules engine or other dedicated mechanism to do it? If not, is it in the roadmap of WSO2 AM to add this kind of features? It would be great.

Answer (score 1):

APIM 3.x onwards UIs are implemented using react and backend services are exposed via REST APIs. SO from this version onwards, this is clearly separated. UI level validations can be changed in the React and if there are any additional validations required, REST API interceptors or workflow interceptors can be used to enforce any validations.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any link with examples about it, either on UI level either through REST API?